# End of line (new line) escapes in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The escape character (`\`) can be used to escape end of line, for example.,

```
echo This could be \
a very \
long line\!
```

Output:

```
This could be a very long line!
```

However, isn't end of line (new line) represented by `\n` which has two characters? Shouldn't the result of the escape be the literal of **`\n`**? For example,

```
echo $'\\n'
```

Output:

```
\n
```

I am not trying to echo a new line. I am wondering why `\` is able to new line character (`\n`) which has two character instead of just escape the backslash in the new line character and produce the literal of `\n`.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Comment: Hmm, still not sure I understand your question. Perhaps it will help to know that `\n` is not _really_ a newline character -- it is an escape sequence that _represents_ a newline (which is just one character in Linux). The `\ ` at the end of a line escapes the _actual_ newline character that you type in using the `enter` key.

Comment: @MarkkuK, thank you! this actually answers my question. I always thought `\n` is the new line character it self. That's why I don't understand why a backslash can escape two characters. Sorry about the bad phrasing.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes when you don't know what you don't know, it's hard to ask a question that makes sense :)

Comment: As a technical addendum to @MarkkuK.'s comment, you can see the newline/linefeed character is a single [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart) value (`10`) on an ASCII table.

Comment: @MarkkuK. You should make your comment an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for the suggestion. I have done so, along with some extra info that may be of use to the OP.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, `\n` is not *really* a newline character—it is an escape sequence that *represents* a newline (which is just one character in Linux). The `\` at the end of a line escapes the *actual* newline character that you type in using the enter key. You can look at what ASCII values represent different characters using [hexdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump):

```
%echo $'\\n'
\n
%echo $'\\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  5c 6e 0a                   |\n.|
00000003
```

You will notice that echo printed out 3 characters: `\` (5c), `n` (6e), and a newline (0a). You will also notice that on the right hand side of the hexdump output, newline shows up as a ".", because it is considered a [non-printing character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Comment: Close, but if you avoid doubling up the `\` and include the `-n` parameter to `echo` to avoid the implicit newline then you get a newline character.

```sh
echo -n $'\n' | hexdump -C
```

Which results in:
```
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
```

Comment: So `\n` escapes the literal meaning of `n` while `\<Enter>` escapes the literal meaning of `<Enter>`, i.e.  `newline`?

Answer (score 1):

Newline is the name given in the UNIX world to a character that ends a line in a line-oriented file (or in a terminal). In the UNIX/Linux world this corresponds to the ASCII linefeed character.

Different systems use different conventions to end lines: Windows uses a sequence of carriage return and line feed, while Mac originally used a single carriage return. This confusion stems from the fact that these were originally commands needed to move a printer's print head to the beginning of a new line.

`\n` is a conventional way of expressing the end of line character in code, again originally in the UNIX world, more precisely in the C language. Note that when reading a text file C reads a single newline character even on systems where this is really a two character sequence.

Comment: In UNIX if a newline is 2 characters, C (or more precisely fread) reads 2 characters. On Windows, if a file is opened as text file, the library will convert the \r\n sequence to \n . Otherwise even on Windows 2 characters will be read.

Comment: In UNIX newline is one character by definition and that's ASCII linefeed or its correspondent in other character sets. It is true that sequences of linefeed and carriage return are read as they are, without translation.